# NullPointerException getting application context when running unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-context

I have a custom Application class, MyApplication (extends Application). I have a getInstance() method in there which just returns itself, so that I can get access to the application Context from anywhere.

I'm trying to unit test a method which calls MyApplication.getInstance(), but it's returning null so my unit test is failing.

Does anybody know how to do this? Or do I need to just pass my application Context into the method to be tested in order to run a test on that method.

Here's some code:

MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    public static MyApplication getInstance()
    {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }
}
```

Method to Test:

```
public static String getErrorMessage(int httpStatus)
{
    // GETTING NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
    Resources resources = Bakery.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getResources();
    // ...
}
```

Unit Test Class:

```
public class ManagerApiTest extends AndroidTestCase
{

    public void testGetErrorMessage() throws Exception
    {
        Resources resources = getContext().getResources();

        String messageInternal = ManagerAPI.getErrorMessage(500);
        assertEquals(resources.getString(R.string.server_error_internal), messageInternal);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't instantiated private static Bakery sInstance;

    public static Bakery getInstance()
    {
        return sInstance;
    }, so calling the get method, will return null. You'll need to mock it.

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske, sInstance is instantiated in onCreate().

Comment: Yes, but I don't see an actuall call to onCreate()

Comment: onCreate() is called by the system upon application creation.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
public static Bakery getInstance()
{
    return sInstance;
}
```

into

```
public static Bakery getInstance()
{
    if(sInstance != null) {
      return sInstance;
    } else {
       return new Bakery();
    }
}
```